# versioning of API documentation in SBT

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I am able to publish API docs using [sbt-ghpages](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-ghpages) plugin. But documentation of the plugin doesn't explain how to maintain multiple versions of the API documentation for each release. How to do this with [sbt-ghpages](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-ghpages) or any other alternatives if available.